# Something about collision

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, collision

> A sphere P of mass m, travelling with speed $u$, makes a head-on collision with a stationary sphere Q also of mass m. After the collision, the velocities of P and Q are $v_1$ and $v_2$ respectively. Which one of the followings is a possible pair values for $v_1$ and $v_2$?
>
> A. $-u, 2u$
>
> B. $u/4, 3u/4$
>
> C. $3u/4, u/4$
>
> D. $u/\sqrt2, u/\sqrt2$

Using conservation of momentum, I know $v_1 + v_2 = u$.

Using energy, I know $u^2 + v^2 \le u^2$.

So I not sure which one, B or C, is the answer.

Comment: You have clearly got a typo in the relation you give as arising from the conservation of energy.

Comment: Some [guidance on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) on Physics.SE.

Answer (score 2):

As the collision is not known to be elastic or inelastic. We just go with checking options , as you did. **a),d)** are easily eliminated . But now **b),c)** gives in problem.

Now we see that after collision the bodies must **separate out**. 
$$0\le\text{coefficient of restitution }(e)\le1 $$

Otherwise $e$ will go negative.

Now we can see in **c)** $e=-1/2$    but in **b)** : $e=1/2$. So, **c** is wrong.

<sub>> All velocities assumed to be in initial direction of motion of P</sub>